# Hibernate5 update only collection many to many relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, jpa-2.0

I have the following diagram mapped with Hibernate 5.2

[image: Diagram Database]

These are my entity classes:

Stock

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "stock", catalog = "mkyongdb", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "STOCK_NAME"),
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "STOCK_CODE") })
public class Stock implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "STOCK_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer stockId;

    @Column(name = "STOCK_CODE", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 10)
    private String stockCode;

    @Column(name = "STOCK_NAME", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 20)
    private String stockName;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinTable(name = "stock_category", catalog = "mkyongdb", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "STOCK_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false) },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "CATEGORY_ID",
                    nullable = false, updatable = false) })
    private Set<Category> categories = new HashSet<>();

    //Getter and Setter

}
```

Category

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "category", catalog = "mkyongdb")
public class Category implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "CATEGORY_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer categoryId;

    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false, length = 10)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "[DESC]", nullable = false)
    private String desc;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "categories", cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    private Set<Stock> stocks = new HashSet<>();

    //Getter and Setter

}
```

Everything works well.

What I need to do is just add a category listing to a stock. I do not want to modify the `Stock` entity, just add or remove categories from the `stock_category` table.

This is my service:

```
@Override
@Transactional(rollbackFor = StockException.class)
public void addCategoriesToStock(Set<Category> categories, Stock stock) throws StockException{
    stock = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Stock.class, stock.getCodStock());
    stock.setCategories(categories);
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(stock);
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();
}
```

This is the test for the service

```
@Test
public void testAddCategoriesStock() throws Exception {
    Stock newValues = new Stock();
    newValues.setStockId(1);
    Category category = new Category();
    category.setCategoryId(13);
    dao.addCategoriesToStock(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(category)), newValues);
    List<Stock> stocks = dao.getAllStockeByCategoriesCriteria(category);
    for (Stock stock : stocks) {
        System.out.println(stock);
    }
}
```

The test runs well without errors, but when browsing the stock associated with category "13" (`getAllStockeByCategoriesCriteria`), it does not bring me any stock. Then the previously executed operation did not work.

What can I do to add or remove categories?

Comment: Should work. Please post `getAllStockeByCategoriesCriteria` implementation and explain how you manage transactions in your tests (maybe changes are not committed)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the first response this is the code I leave in the method.

Change the signature because I only need the identifiers of the entities to be able to relate them and as indicated Maciej Kowalski the relationship must stay both ways

I also changed the lists by Set to make sure the values were not going to be duplicated

This would be my service to add a list of categories to the relationship

```
@Override
@Transactional(rollbackFor = StockException.class)
public void addCategoriesToStock(Set<Integer> categoryCodes, Integer codStock) throws StockException{
    //I get the stock I'm going to associate
    Stock stock = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Stock.class, codStock);
    if (categoryCodes != null) {
    //For each category to add to the stock, I consult and add the relationship in both entities
        for (Integer codCategory : categoryCodes) {
            Category category = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Category.class, codCategory);
            category.add(stock);
            stock.add(category);
        }
    }
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().merge(stock);
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();
}
```

This would be the service to remove a list of categories from the relationship

```
@Override
@Transactional(rollbackFor = StockException.class)
public void removeCategoriesToStock(Set<Integer> categoryCodes, Integer codStock) throws StockException{
    //I get the stock that I will disassociate
    Stock stock = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Stock.class, codStock);
    if (categoryCodes != null) {
    //For each category to eliminate the stock, I consult and eliminate the relationship in both entities
        for (Integer codCategory : categoryCodes) {
            Category category = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Category.class, codCategory);
            category.remove(stock);
            stock.remove(category);
        }
    }
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().merge(stock);
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();
}
```

The doubt I have is that before I can make the relationship between both entities I have to consult them in the database to get the object and manipulate it. As this I have to do it for each identifier that I will associate there should be a performance problem I suppose.

But for the moment I'll leave it in case I find a more optimal way to do so post it here

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the dependencies on both sides, so you are missing the addition of Stock to `categories`:

```
@Override
@Transactional(rollbackFor = StockException.class)
public void addCategoriesToStock(List<Category> categories, Stock stock) throws StockException{
    stock = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Stock.class, stock.getCodStock());
    stock.setCategories(categories);

    for(Category cat: categories){
        cat.getStocks().add(stock);
    }

    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().merge(stock);
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();
}
```

Also i think you should use `merge` instead of `update` for the cascade to work.

After that your code should save the relationships.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But having to go through the entire list of categories and add the stock will affect the performance of the application or not?

Comment: Its an in-memory operation.. Compared to actual physical saving of the linkage table same amount of times it should not be that noticable.

Comment: But if I need to, for example, add or delete just one category, I would have to get the whole list and go through it to add or delete the new object ?